# Find URI based on literal variable using FILTER and REGEX

Tags: sparql, skos

I need to find URIs of skos:Concept using skos:prefLabel (literal) from other skos:Concept. Here is my query:

```
SELECT ?variableURI ?variablePref ?entityPrefRegex ?entityURI ?entityPref WHERE {
    ?variableURI skos:prefLabel ?variablePref .
    FILTER(REGEX(?variablePref,"^Dissolved .* in surface water"))
    BIND(REPLACE(?variablePref,"^Dissolved (.*) concentration in surface water", "$1") AS ?entityPrefRegex).
    ?entityURI skos:prefLabel ?entityPref .
    FILTER(REGEX(?entityPref,?entityPrefRegex,"i")) 
}
```

**My problem is that the filtering part return no result and I don't understand why.**

Here are sample variables I'm trying to link my entities

| variableURI | variablePref | entityPrefRegex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| <:c_7e508e0e> | "Dissolved aluminium concentration in surface water"@en | "aluminium"@en |
| <:c_b5dec35c> | "Dissolved arsenic concentration in surface water"@en | "arsenic"@en |
| <:c_bc765ffd> | "Dissolved boron concentration in surface water"@en | "boron"@en |
| <:c_4ce4d2c7> | "Dissolved caesium concentration in surface water"@en | "caesium"@en |

And the corresponding entities. As you can see the literal are identical except for the capital letter.

| entityURI | entityPref |
| --- | --- |
| <:c_d57d0742> | "Aluminium"@en |
| <:c_d57d077> | "Arsenic"@en |
| <:c_d57d0728> | "Boron"@en |
| <:c_d57d0745> | "Caesium"@en |

Comment: the regex pattern is the second argument of the function `regex`, so it should be at least `FILTER(REGEX(?entityPref, ?entityPrefRegex, "i"))` - you should also consider to get the lexical form of literals, i.e. you should do `FILTER(REGEX(STR(?entityPref), STR(?entityPrefRegex),"i"))`, otherwise the filter will be evaulated to error because the pattern has to be a string and not a literal, thus, in the end the filter evaluates to false

Comment: a dummy query works for me with the fix: `SELECT * {
VALUES ?variablePref {"Dissolved aluminium concentration in surface water"@en}
VALUES ?entityPref {"Aluminium"@en}
    FILTER(REGEX(?variablePref,"^Dissolved .* in surface water"))
    BIND(REPLACE(?variablePref,"^Dissolved (.*) concentration in surface water", "$1") AS ?entityPrefRegex).
    FILTER(REGEX(STR(?entityPref), STR(?entityPrefRegex),"i")) 
}`

Comment: Thanks the STR() mehtod does the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern (second) argument to `REGEX` is a "simple literal" (a literal "without language tag or datatype IRI"). In this case, it looks like you are using `?entityPref` values that have the `@en` language tag:

```
FILTER(REGEX(?entityPrefRegex,?entityPref,"i"))
```

Try instead casting the pattern to a plain string:

```
FILTER(REGEX(?entityPrefRegex,STR(?entityPref),"i"))
```